# swift didSet not called in a singleton

Tags: swift

Lets say I have a singleton Manager

```
 class Manager {

    static let sharedInstance = Manager()

    var text: String {
        didSet (value) { print("didSet \(value)") }
    }

    init () {
        self.text = "hello"
    } 
 }
```

If I do

```
Manager.sharedInstance.text = "world"
```

text is still 'hello'
but if I do it twice, the second time it is world

Comment: looks like using willSet works as expected but not didSet

Comment: I don't think property observers are invoked during initialisation.

Comment: but I am not expecting it to, I am accessing it later

Comment: So you should see the observer invoked once with `value == hello` and `text == world` (value is the old value). Change the observer to `print("didSet \(value)->\(text)")`

Comment: To me, this sounds like a bug! RADAR time!

Comment: ok so it is just my misunderstanding that didSet(value) value is the old value instead of the new value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is working fine.

The behaviour your experienced is explained by 2 facts

### Fact 1

As Apple [says](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html) `didSet` (and `willSet` as well) is **not** called during the `init`.

> The willSet and didSet observers provide a way to observe (and to
>   respond appropriately) when the value of a variable or property is
>   being set. The observers are not called when the variable or property
>   is first initialized. Instead, they are called only when the value is
>   set outside of an initialization context.

### Fact 2

The parameter of `didSet` does refer to the **old value**, so you should

1. rename `value` as `oldValue`.
2. use `text` in the `print`

So from this

```
didSet (value) { print("didSet \(value)") }
```

to this

```
didSet (oldValue) { print("didSet \(text)") }
```

Instead in your code you are printing the old value (the one that has been overwritten).

Comment: as I said, I am not expecting it to be called during the init, I already set the default value in init, but the fact that after it has been initialized it is not called when I set the new value for exemple Manager.sharedInstance; Manager.sharedInstance.text = "world" does not work but Manager.sharedInstance.text = "world;  Manager.sharedInstance.text = "world" works